# Linux Ubuntu 12.04 - TeamViewer 8 - microphone/speakers problem

Tags: 12.04, microphone, teamviewer

I already install Teamviewer 8 on my laptop (Linux Ubuntu 12.04)
But there is no sound - no microphone or speakers can be detected from TeamViewer.
Is there any way that I can fix that problem ?

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: TeamViewer 8 is ancient, use Team Viewer 10

Answer (score 1):

Teamviewer 8 is actually running through wine, and is not a native Linux application per se, but rather an application ported to run atop Wine. You might try reviewing your wine configuration to determine if your wine config recognises your hardware. It should, but it may not. An updated version of Wine may also help resolve the issue if you are following the Ubuntu Wine Team ppa you might note that many updates have occurred for Wine since the first 12.04 LTS release.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by running:

```
WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.config/teamviewer8 winecfg
```

Comment: This worked for me once I realized that I had to install wine (Teamviewer doesn't come with winecfg).  Once done, in the winecfg display I went to the Audio tab and selected the system's audio device in the output boxes. All good then.   Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience (Linux Mint Quiana + Teamviewer 10):

1. Install Wine
2. Download latest Teamviewer from [teamviewer.com](http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb)
3. Installation

   ```
   $ dpkg -i teamviewer_10.0.36281_i386.deb 

   -> dependencies error : 
   dpkg: error processing package teamviewer (--install):
    problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
   Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
    teamviewer

   $ apt-get -f install
   ```

   then redo the installation:

   ```
   dpkg -i teamviewer_10.0.36281_i386.deb
   ```

Done, working fine, including audio !